# Relation between the Euler characteristic of a log pair and it's dimension?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $(X,D:=\sum_{i=1}^k D_i)$ be a log smooth pair with $D_i$ prime div on $X$ and $-K_X-D$ is big and nef. Define $M:=-K_X-D$, and get that $\chi(X,K_X+lM)=0$.
By Hirzeburch-Riemann-Roch formula, we know that $\chi(X,K_X+lM)$ is a polynomial of degree $d$ with leading term $\frac{M^d}{d!}l^d$. This implies that $\chi(X,K_X+lM)=0$ cannot have $d+1$ distinct roots. And they claim that this is a contradiction. But I don't understand why it is a contradiction. Is there a property of $\chi$ I am missing?